# Controller doesn't recognizes Template using ModelAndView

Tags: java, spring-boot, templates, thymeleaf, modelandview

I'm having some problems that i don't know how to solve. I need to add an "new house" system to my real estate advertisement site. So i added a button in the advertise management page linking to a dashboard page, when i click the button, it goes to a whitelabel error page with this error:

```html
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//dashboard-locador.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//dashboard-locador.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1400)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Cannot process attribute '{th:field,data-th-field}': no associated BindStatus could be found for the intended form binding operations. This can be due to the lack of a proper management of the Spring RequestContext, which is usually done through the ThymeleafView or ThymeleafReactiveView (template: "/dashboard-locador" - line 70, col 92)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Cannot process attribute '{th:field,data-th-field}': no associated BindStatus could be found for the intended form binding operations. This can be due to the lack of a proper management of the Spring RequestContext, which is usually done through the ThymeleafView or ThymeleafReactiveView (template: "/dashboard-locador" - line 70, col 92)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:177)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95)
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:304)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:278)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:186)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:124)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:109)
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402)
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301)
    ... 50 more
```

Advertise management page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/dashboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/global-style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fe8dd15147.js" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script src="script/script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="script/aaa.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Coda&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVBAR  -->
    <header class="cabecalho">
        <div class="navBar-container">
            <nav class="navBar">
                <h1>Logo</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Imóveis</li>
                    <li>Sobre Nós</li>
                    <li>Suporte</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="login-singin">
                    <div class="button">CADASTRO</div>
                    <div class="button invert-button"><img src="icons/perfil.svg"> LOGIN</div>
                </div>
                <button class="menu" onclick="">
                    <img src="icons/Menu.svg">
                </button>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        <div class="cabecalho-meus-imoveis">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Voltar a Meus Imoveis</a>
            <h2>Endereço do Negócio</h2>
        </div>
        </header>
<main>
<!-- CRIAR ANUNCIO  -->
<div class="servicos-dashboard">
    <div class="preco-dashboard">
       <input type="number" class="preco-dashboard" placeholder="R$ 999999.99999">
       <a th:href="@{dashboard}"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i>CRIAR PUBLICAÇÃO</a>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Dashboard page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/dashboard.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/global-style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fe8dd15147.js" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
    <script src="script/script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="script/aaa.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Coda&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVBAR  -->
    <header class="cabecalho">
        <div class="navBar-container">
            <nav class="navBar">
                <h1>Logo</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>Imóveis</li>
                    <li>Sobre Nós</li>
                    <li>Suporte</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="login-singin">
                    <div class="button">CADASTRO</div>
                    <div class="button invert-button"><img src="icons/perfil.svg"> LOGIN</div>
                </div>
                <button class="menu" onclick="">
                    <img src="icons/Menu.svg">
                </button>
            </nav>
        </div>
        
        <div class="cabecalho-meus-imoveis">
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i> Voltar a Meus Imoveis</a>
            <h2>Endereço do Negócio</h2>
        </div>
        </header>
<!--  -->


<main>
<section class="informacoes-servico">
    <div class="carrossel"> 
        
        <img src="assets/803_df899154-e3b9-4e5f-a1fb-6b23820b6011_thm.jpg" class="imagems-carrossel active "alt="">
        <img src="assets/96026334.jpg" class="imagems-carrossel" alt="">
        <img src="assets/maxresdefault.jpg" class="imagems-carrossel" alt="">
        <img src="assets/unnamed.jpg" class="imagems-carrossel" alt="">
        <img src="assets/Imagem1.png" class="imagems-carrossel" alt="">
      
        <button class="btn-carrossel"></button>
        <button class="btn-carrossel-1"></button>
        <div class="bolinhas" id="bolinha"></div>
    </div>
<!-- DESCRICAO DO IMOVEL  -->
<div class="servicos-dashboard">
    <div class="preco-dashboard">
      <input type="number" class="preco-dashboard" placeholder="R$ 9999.99">
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i>EDITAR PUBLICAÇÃO</a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-pen"></i>EXCLUIR PUBLICAÇÃO</a>
    </div>
   
    <div class="descricao-dashboard">        
        <h2>DESCRIÇÃO</h2>
        <textarea rows="5" colls="33" placeholder="Insira sua descrição" maxlength="1000"  th:field="*"></textarea>
   </div>

    <div class="dados-imovel-dashboard">
        <h2>DADOS DO IMOVEL </h2>
        <div class="dados-imovel-dashboard-especificacoes">
            <div class="especificacoes-info">
                <span class="titulo-especificacao-dashboard">Cidade</span>
                <input class="conteudo-especificacao-dashboard" placeholder="Ex: Cidade" th:field="*"></input>
            </div>
            
            <div class="especificacoes-info">
                <span class="titulo-especificacao-dashboard">Bairro</span>
                <input class="conteudo-especificacao-dashboard"  placeholder="Ex: Osasco-Beach"></input>
            </div>
            
            <div class="especificacoes-info">
                <span class="titulo-especificacao-dashboard">Construido em</span>
                <input class="conteudo-especificacao-dashboard" placeholder="Ex: 2003" th:field="*"></input>
            </div>
            
            <div class="especificacoes-info">
                <span class="titulo-especificacao-dashboard">Vigilância</span>
                <input class="conteudo-especificacao-dashboard" placeholder="Ex: 24" th:field="*"></input>
            </div>
            
            <div class="especificacoes-info">
                <span class="titulo-especificacao-dashboard">Estacionamento</span>
                <input class="conteudo-especificacao-dashboard"placeholder="Sim" th:field="*"></input>
            </div>
            
            <div class="especificacoes-info">
                <span class="titulo-especificacao-dashboard">Tamanho m²</span>
                <input class="conteudo-especificacao-dashboard " placeholder="100m²" th:field="*"></input>
            </div>
            
            <div class="especificacoes-info">
                <span class="titulo-especificacao-dashboard">Banheiros</span>
                <input class="conteudo-especificacao-dashboard" placeholder="4" th:field="*"></input>
            </div>
            
            <!-- ALTERAR APÓS COMPONENTIZAÇÃO -->
            <div class="especificacoes-info">
                <span class="titulo-especificacao-dashboard">Preço por m²</span>
                <input class="conteudo-especificacao-dashboard" placeholder="R$ 300" th:field="*"></input>
            </div>
        </div>

</div>
</div>
</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Dashboard controller code:

```html
package icarus.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import icarus.model.Imoveis;

@Controller
public class DashboardController {

@GetMapping("/dashboard")
public ModelAndView InsertImovel(Imoveis imovel) {
    
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("/dashboard-locador");
    mv.addObject("imovel", new Imoveis());
    return mv;
}
    
}
```

(sorry for my poor english)

Comment: You are using `th:field` without a form. The value should normally also be a property name. Maybe have a look to https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/ for some more information on how to use forms in Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check to see if your template file path is correct.

`mv.setViewName("/dashboard-locador");`

Modify to

`mv.setViewName("dashboard-locador")`

And check to see if your template file exists in your `resources\templates` directory.
Because the default template directory of thymeleaf is `resources\templates`.

Finally, check that the view parser is configured correctly

Refer to thymeleaf default configuration source code

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.thymeleaf")
public class ThymeleafProperties {

    private static final Charset DEFAULT_ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

    public static final String DEFAULT_PREFIX = "classpath:/templates/";

    public static final String DEFAULT_SUFFIX = ".html";
}
```